Why is connection not secured when using on demand tls in Caddy?
I have a SaaS app that in short allows users to create a simple online eshop. I let users to verify their custom domain in order to let them host their store on their domain.
To achieve this by having a Caddy server in a separate machine that serves as a reverse proxy and is automatically generating ssl certificates on demand.
The issue is that when someone verifies their domain, whe they visit their domain, the website is shown as "not secure" in their browser. It should be secured, Caddy should redirect automatically to https.
If they enter https:// manually, redirect starts working and for some time it's no longer possible to access http. The redirect should be permanent.
My app I hosted on Render.com which handles https automatically for non custom domain requests. Caddy is hosted on Hetzner
This is roughly my Caddy config
{
        on_demand_tls {
                ask {{REMIX_APP_URL}}/api/ask
        }
        servers {
                metrics
        }
        admin :2019
}

http://, https:// {
        # log json
        tls {
                on_demand
        }

        reverse_proxy {
                to https://{{REMIX_APP_URL}}
                header_up Host {http.reverse_proxy.upstream.host}
        }
}

